# Is hosting a Discord music bot on serverless infrastructure possible?

Tags: discord, discord.js, serverless, ytdl

I've been running a custom Discord bot on a VPS for a while, but to streamline the development/deployment process and bring it in line with my other personal projects, I've been considering moving it to [Cloudflare Workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com).

Discord fully supports serverless bots via the interactions API and even has a [demo](https://github.com/discord/cloudflare-sample-app) for deploying one specifically with Cloudflare workers.

Unfortunately, complications arise when streaming audio from YouTube into voice channels comes into scope.

[node-ytdl-core](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core) can be used to access a YouTube audio stream and [discordjs/voice](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-resources.html#cheat-sheet) can be used to broadcast it into a voice channel, but [CF Workers has a limit](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#worker-limits) of 10ms CPU runtime per request, rendering it obviously useless for streaming a 3 minute long track.

It seems that if using the paid plan with unbound usage limit, the [streams API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/using-streams/) could be leveraged to quickly return the initial response, but keep streaming the track afterwards in the background, however this would likely be cost prohibitive.

Is there any feasible way for me to convert to Cloudflare serverless infra while preserving my bot's music playing functionality?

The only prior art in this regard I've stumbled upon in this regard is this 5 year old [repo](https://github.com/gaymers-discord/serverless-music-bot/blob/master/index.js) that I have not been able to get to work nor can I see why it would work.